# Makefile for host & target

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, makefile, host

My question is about compiling error on linux. Every time I try to compile the program it gives me this error. I tried different things without luck.

*** No rule to make target '/pthread.d', needed by '/thread.exe'.  Stop.

The makefile for the program ( pthread is as follow:

```
SOURCES=pthread.cpp   
OBJECTS=$(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))   
DEPS=$(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(SOURCES:.cpp=.d))   
EXE=thread.exe    
CXXFLAGS=-I.    
LIBS=-pthread    

//Making for host > make ARCH=host
ifeq ($(ARCH),host)    
CXX=g++    
BUILD_DIR=build/host    
BIN_DIR=bin/host    
endif    


//Making for target > make ARCH= target    
ifeq ($(ARCH),target)    
CXX=arm-rpizw-g++    
BUILD_DIR=build/target    
BIN_DIR=bin/target    
endif    

all: $(BIN_DIR)/$(EXE)    

$(BIN_DIR)/$(EXE): $(DEPS) $(OBJECTS)    
    mkdir -p $(BIN_DIR)    
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJECTS)    

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.d: %.cpp    
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)     
    $(CXX) -MT$(@:.d=.o) -MM $(CXXFLAGS) $^ > $@    

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp    
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)    
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)    

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS), $(filter $(MAKECMDGOALS),clean help))    
-include $(DEPS)    
endif    

clean:    
    -rm -rf bin/    
    -rm -rf build/
```

Comment: This is not your problem but it's a bad idea. `SOURCES=pthread.cpp` consider naming your source files something more unique so it won't be confused with official library files. Not that `pthread.cpp` exists in any library, but consider for example if your header for that source was called `pthread.h`... yikes

Comment: Thanks Justin, It is a good point. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have spaces after `BUILD_DIR=build/target`.   Thus, `$(DEPS)` resolves to:

```
 build/target   /pthread.d
```

..., and thus make will try to make `/pthread.d` (and `build/target`...).   When assigning a value, make discards any preceding spaces, but not trailing spaces.   It will drop a trailing comment, but it will not drop whitespace between the end of the line and the comment.

For debugging this type of problem, it's often useful to add `$(info)` lines into your makefile as so:

```
$(info DEPS=_$(DEPS)_)
```

and then run to see if there are any unexpected values.

Comment: thanks for the useful comment. There was both what you have suggested and a few other simple mistakes, which I solved the issue now. It's indeed nice with the info variable.